# What is the source of truth for currently active tty/pts connections?

Tags: linux, kernel, users, python, devices

I'm looking for a simple way to determine the number of currently logged in users, using only the filesystem and basic bash functions (instead of using binaries).

The `uptime` binary appears to be reading from `/var/run/utmp` according the its source code, but `/var/run/utmp` doesn't seem to update in real time (it shows `tty7` and `pts/1-5` for my user, but I'm only on `tty7` and `pts/5` at the moment). However, the `uptime` binary correctly shows "2 users".

Note: Instead of relying on `uptime` or `getutent()` in C, I'm trying to better understand how the underlying system works.

What's the best place to find a current, accurate number of users logged into the system?

Comment: The [utmp man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/utmp.5.html) contains some background information. In my opinion, it is not possible (or at least really painful) to interpret utmp files with only basic shell functions. There is also `who` which shows the current allocated terminals.

Comment: I'm actually writing some Python to decode utmp, but it's still very painful. I'm trying to avoid relying on subprocess calls to existing binaries, and force myself to use the actual Linux filesystem contents to gather data in order to learn more about Linux/procfs/utmp.

Answer (score 2):

You can see how many pty's are allocated by looking at `/proc/sys/kernel/pty/nr`, however that won't necessarily be *how many* people are logged in.

For instance, on one of my servers I am currently the only person logged in but there are *7* pty's in use because of users running `screen`.

Comment: This is very helpful - I'll play with it tonight. Thanks!